# How do I swap data between columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, swap

Suppose I have the following data:

```
vec1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,16,17,18,19,20)
vec2 <- c(11,12,13,14,15,NA,6,7,8,9,10)
sample_df <- as.data.frame(vec1)
sample_df$vec2 <- vec2
```

When I print `sample_df`, I receive the following output:

```
    vec1 vec2
1     1   11
2     2   12
3     3   13
4     4   14
5     5   15
6    NA   NA
7    16    6
8    17    7
9    18    8
10   19    9
11   20   10
```

Suppose I want my output to look as follows:

```
   vec1 vec2
1     1   11
2     2   12
3     3   13
4     4   14
5     5   15
6    NA   NA
7     6   16
8     7   17
9     8   18
10    9   19
11   10   20
```

How would I manage to do this without editing either of the vectors?

Comment: Try `sample_df[7:11, ] <- sample_df[7:11, 2:1]`

Answer (score 1):

We specify the row index and reverse the order of columns while assigning the values

```
sample_df[7:11, ] <- sample_df[7:11, rev(seq_along(sample_df))]
```

Comment: What if I wanted to make this a pattern? For instance, rather than specifying rows, I say at every other five rows this occurs. How would I do this?

Comment: `seq(from=1,to=nrow(sample_df), by=5)` instead of `7:11` might be a way to do it

Comment: So my code should look as follows: `sample_df[seq(from=1,to=nrow(sample_df), by=5), ] <- sample_df[
seq(from=1,to=nrow(sample_df), by=5), rev(seq_along(sample_df))]` . This doesn't appear to work for me.

Comment: @ArnavHarkenavvy  This is based on the question posted. `i1 <- seq(from = 1, to = nrow(sample_df), by = 5); sample_df[i1, ] <- sample_df[i1, rev(seq_along(sample_df))]`

Comment: I don't understand what `doesn't work for me`.  It is working for me.  For e.g. `i1 <- seq(from = 1, to = nrow(sample_df), by = 3);sample_df[i1, ] <- sample_df[i1, rev(seq_along(sample_df))]`